# XText Chained Dependencies in Type Inference

Tags: types, dsl, type-inference, xtext

In my experiments, it appears that XText cannot resolve variable types when there is a chain of dependencies across multiple XExpression blocks.

A minimal example, to illustrate. I have a grammar:

```
grammar eg.types.inference.TypeInferenceExample with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase 

generate typeInferenceExample "example.org/types/inference/TypeInferenceExample"

Model:
    blocks += Block*
;

Block:
    '{'
        'name' ':' name=QualifiedName
        'from' ':' ('none' | from=[Block|QualifiedName])
        'block' ':' expression=XBlockExpression
    '}'
;
```

An interface:

```
package eg.lib;

public interface IModelBlock {
    public void push(org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Pair<String, ?> toPush);
}
```

And a JvmModelInferrer:

```
package eg.types.inference.jvmmodel

import com.google.inject.Inject
import eg.lib.IModelBlock
import eg.types.inference.typeInferenceExample.Block
import eg.types.inference.typeInferenceExample.Model
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.XBinaryOperation
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.XExpression
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.XFeatureCall
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.XStringLiteral
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.AbstractModelInferrer
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmTypesBuilder

class TypeInferenceExampleJvmModelInferrer extends AbstractModelInferrer {

    @Inject extension JvmTypesBuilder

    def dispatch void infer(Model model, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
        model.blocks.forEach [block |
            acceptor.accept(block.toClass(block.name)).initializeLater [
                superTypes += block.newTypeRef(typeof(IModelBlock))
                members += block.toMethod("invoke", newTypeRef(Void::TYPE)) [
                    if (block.from != null) {
                        block.from.pushType.forEach [p |
                            parameters += block.toParameter(p.key, p.value)
                        ]
                    }
                    body = block.expression
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }

    def private pushType(Block block) {
        return block.eAllContents.filter[ // List of push calls in this Block
            it instanceof XFeatureCall && (it as XFeatureCall).concreteSyntaxFeatureName.equals("push")
        ].map [ 
            val call = it as XFeatureCall
            // Add entry for push call as an OutputDeclaration
            return call.featureCallArguments.map[
                if (!(it instanceof XBinaryOperation)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Must push using -> operator")
                }
                val key = (it as XBinaryOperation).leftOperand
                val value = (it as XBinaryOperation).rightOperand
                return key.name -> value.inferredType
            ]
        ].head
    }

    def private String name(XExpression literal) {
        if (!(literal instanceof XStringLiteral)) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Literal was not a string literal")
        }
        return (literal as XStringLiteral).value
    }

}
```

When I create a simple example for this DSL, such as:

```
{
    name : BlockOne
    from : none
    block : {
        val i = 42 * 3.6
        push("index" -> i)
    }
}

{
    name : BlockTwo
    from : BlockOne
    block : {
        val res = "Another Value from " + index
        push("result" -> res)
    }
}
```

Code is generated just fine (type inference successfully works out the types of `index` and `res` in generating the output Java). I am using the pairs in the call to `push` on `BlockOne` to infer an interface on the invoke method for `BlockTwo`. This `push` method comes from the `IModelBlock` interface above. If I add a third Block to this example, thus:

```
{
    name : BlockThree
    from : BlockTwo
    block : {
        val out = "This one came from: " + result
        push("out" -> out)
    }
}
```

Inference fails, with an `UnsupportedOperationException: TODO: import a functional handle on the type resolution that delegates to the best available (current, but evolving) result` (from `OnChangeEvictingCache.execWithoutCacheClear`, `CachingBatchTypeResolver.resolveTypes`).

**Is there some other technique I should use to derive the types of variables which have chained dependencies like this in XText?**

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

This seem to have been a bug in the version you use. Try with the latest one.

Comment: I've just tried with XText 2.5.0 (R201312110906 according to the documentation) and it threw the same exception. Am I missing an update site?